# create a policy in selinux for a socket file with the regular expression

Tags: linux, selinux

```
/ # ls -lZ /var/run/wpa_ctrl_1790-1
srwxr-xr-x    1 root     root     system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0           0 Jun 12 14:52 [1;35m/var/run/wpa_ctrl_1790-1
/ #
```

Wpa_ctrl_(some_number) , (some_number) can change everytime when a different instance of wpa_cli is started. And it is a socket file which is created runtime.

I tried including the below change, but it did not work.

```
/var/run/wpa_ctrl_.*             -- gen_context(system_u:object_r:NetworkManager_var_run_t,s0)
```

The above change never changed the context of wpa_ctrl_(some_number) to NetworkManager_var_run_t

Comment: Newly created files by default inherit the context of their parent folder, not the one specified in the rules, unless restorecon is applied on that file. Depending on the details of your system, there might be some call to restorecon during start-up, but if your sockets are created dynamically, that might be too early. You could try calling e.g. `restorecon /var/run/your_socket` or `restorecon -R /var/run` to confirm that this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: **restorecon -R /var/run/wpa_ctrl_1568-1** command will still says that the older context is also var_run_t.

**ls -lZ /var/run/wpa_ctrl_1568-1
srwxr-xr-x    1 root     root     system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0           0 Jun 12 14:16 /var/run/wpa_ctrl_1568-1**

Is this correct?
**/var/run/wpa_ctrl_.*             -- gen_context(system_u:object_r:NetworkManager_var_run_t,s0)**

Comment: I don't have the gen_context macro on my system, but using an already defined context works fine for me. Can you specify some more details of your setup, i.e. which Linux distribution you are using and in which file you put that line?